# How can I increase space between table data?

Tags: html, css

I was originally going to upload an image but this isn't possible because I don't have 10 reputation yet. So I will try to describe my problem. At the moment I am using bootstrap to put some styling on a table, however once I do this the table data becomes too close together then what I would prefer it to be. Is there a way to numerically increase the space between table data?

Code is as follows:

```css
#TableTotal{
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="TableTotal">
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL PLAN</td>
    <td>£1,200,000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL ACTUALS</td>
    <td>£1400,090.267</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL VARIENCE</td>
    <td id="Positive">+£3,990,267.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add css padding on td tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some padding only in the first column

Try:

```css
#TableTotal td:first-child {
    padding-right: 20px; /*Or how much space you need*/
}
```

```css
#TableTotal {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
#TableTotal td:first-child {
  padding-right: 20px; /*Or how much space you need*/
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="TableTotal">
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL PLAN</td>
    <td>£1,200,000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL ACTUALS</td>
    <td>£1400,090.267</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL VARIENCE</td>
    <td id="Positive">+£3,990,267.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll select this answer ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

You add `cellpadding="10"` attribute in table tag

```
<table cellpadding="10">
```

but it not supported in html 5, instead of this you can use CSS for spacing

```
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/5/

https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/6/

Comment: Apparently I accidentally hit the downvote button. Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property. In the [separated borders model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-collapse), it sets the distance between horizontal and vertical borders of adjacent cells.

```css
#TableTotal {
  border-spacing: 20px 2px;
}
```

```css
#TableTotal {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  border-spacing: 20px 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="TableTotal">
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL PLAN</td>
    <td>£1,200,000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL ACTUALS</td>
    <td>£1400,090.267</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TOTAL VARIENCE</td>
    <td id="Positive">+£3,990,267.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```